# Wia API - Error on changing transfer file format

Tags: c++, windows, format, wia

I tried to control my Wifi scanner using the Windows Wia API.

I followed the tutorial on: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-wia-tutorial

And I looked at the Examples:
https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/wia

I basically copied the code from the **datatransfer** project:
https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/wia/datatransfer

And everthing works fine. I can communicate with my scanner and scan a document to a ".BMP" file.

Now I'd like to play around with some settings.I startet with trying to change the file format.

in **DataTransfer.cpp**:
https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/multimedia/wia/datatransfer/DataTransfer.cpp

The scan happens in `HRESULT DownloadItem(IWiaItem2* pWiaItem2 , BOOL bTransferFlag)`. 
I thought the file format is specified there:

```c
HRESULT DownloadItem(IWiaItem2* pWiaItem2 , BOOL bTransferFlag
{
    ...

                    GUID itemCategory = GUID_NULL;
                    ReadPropertyGuid(pWiaItem2,WIA_IPA_ITEM_CATEGORY,&itemCategory );

                    if( (!IsEqualIID(itemCategory,WIA_CATEGORY_FINISHED_FILE)) || (!IsEqualIID(itemCategory,WIA_CATEGORY_FOLDER)) )
                    {                     
                        /* WiaImgFmt_BMP sets the format to ".BMP" */
                        hr = WritePropertyGuid(pWiaPropertyStorage,WIA_IPA_FORMAT,WiaImgFmt_BMP);
                    }

                    if(FAILED(hr))
                    {
                        ReportError(TEXT("WritePropertyGuid() failed in DownloadItem().Format couldn't be set to BMP"),hr);
                    }

    ...

}
```

So i tried to change `WiaImgFmt_BMP` to other formats like `WiaImgFmt_JPEG` or `WiaImgFmt_PNG`
but they return the Error: `HRESLUT: 0x80070057`.

How can I make this work ?

I thought that maybe the scanner doesn't support the other formats, but I don't know how to check that.
When I researched this, I only found reference to the Wia Mini Driver. But I don't quite understand the difference between the API and the driver. If somebody could explain this to me I'd appreciate it.

Windows fax and scan does provide the PNG, JPEG format and I think they also use Wia, so I'd be surprised if the formats aren't supported.

Comment: Ok, so I found out, that HRESLUT: 0x8007005 means, that I don't have access rights.
If I look at WIA_IPA_ACCESS_RIGHTS it is also set to WIA_ITEM_READ, which means read only.

Answer (score 1):

I think it only support BMP and JPEG, you can use IWiaTransfer::EnumWIA_FORMAT_INFO method to know the format it support.